# Add Items on Combo Box depending on the Cell Color

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel-VBA and I'm trying to add items in combo box depending on the cell color.

In this example, I only want the text of those blue shades be added on the combobox list.

[image]

```
Sheets("Application").ComboBox1.List = Range("A:A").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will go through out column A and if it finds a cell with specific color, it will add it to the combobox, this will occurred every time the sheet gets activated.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Me.ComboBox1.Clear

With Sheets("Application")

LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If .Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then

If Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 12611584 Then
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(i, 1)
End If

End If

Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Bro!

I had to change this line because I find it easier to set color.


If Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96) Then